# How to Programmatically switch between two screens

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-xp, screen, multiscreen

I have a program in C# that uses two screens for displayin few windows.
Is there a (simple) way to switch between the screens so I will have all the content of one screen on the other and vice versa?
I've tried to look for some win32api option but didn't find anything helpfull....

b.t.w
I'm using windows xp.

thanks,
Yossi.

Comment: by screens you mean physical lcds or your own windows?

Comment: Try refs at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031687/how-to-change-3rd-monitor-programatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547329/execute-automatic-change-connected-displays-in-windows-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625057/rotating-displays-programmatically-in-windows-xp-c-qt-and-windowsapi?rq=1

Comment: or this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651909/specifying-startup-window-form-location-on-multiple-displays

Comment: The class `System.Windows.Forms.Screens` gives you information about your available screens. You can use that information to change the property `Left` of your window/form to the bounds of the second screen.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the responds. Few more points: By "screens" I mean physical lcds... And since I canhave few opened windows at the same time - I would like to switch the whole display and not moving each window from side to side. Is this possible?

Comment: I think there is no simpler way as moving each window. Maybe you can get each open window of your application and then move them (like a list of open windows or window manager)