# vertical placement of monitor

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

How to set monitor in vertical position?

[image: Vertical Alignment]

code below can set resolution and refresh rate but i cant figure out how to set both monitor in vertical position.

i have tried with dm.dmDisplayOrientation but did not worked.
is there anything more to configure while setting display to vertical alignment.

vertical alignment work when set using windows display settings.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetDisplay("DELL S2240L(Analog)",0,0,1600,900,60,false);
    SetDisplay("DELL S2240L(Hdmi)",0,900,1600,1800,60,true);
    return 0;
}

bool SetDisplay(std::string monitorname,int pox,int poy,int w,int h,int r,bool parent)
{
    DWORD iDevNum(0);
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(dd);

    while ( EnumDisplayDevices(0, iDevNum, &dd, 0) )
    {
        if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP)
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE dd2;
            dd2.cb = sizeof(dd2);
            EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, 0, &dd2, 0);

            if(monitorname.compare(dd2.DeviceString)==0)
            {                   
                DEVMODE dm;
                ZeroMemory(&dm ,sizeof(dm));
                dm.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
                if (!EnumDisplaySettings(dd.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
                {
                    std::cout <<"EnumDisplaySettings failed:%d\n"<< GetLastError()<< std::endl;
                    return FALSE;
                }


                dm.dmPelsWidth = w;
                dm.dmPelsHeight = h;

                POINTL po;
                po.x=pox;
                po.y=poy;
                dm.dmPosition = po;
                dm.dmDisplayFrequency = r;


                dm.dmFields = (DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY | DM_POSITION );//| DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION );


                if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, CDS_TEST) !=DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
                {
                    std::cout << "Illegal graphics mode: %d\n"<< GetLastError()<< std::endl;                
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "can be applied on "<< dd.DeviceString<< std::endl;
                }

                std::cout << "try applied on "<< dm.dmDeviceName<< std::endl;


                ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(dd.DeviceName, &dm, NULL, CDS_FULLSCREEN| CDS_SET_PRIMARY  , NULL);

            }
            else
            {
                std::cout <<" no "<<monitorname.c_str()<<" =="<<dd2.DeviceString  << std::endl;
            }    
        }
        ++iDevNum;
    }
}
```

**Screen Before alignment**
[image: screen before]

**Screen After alignment**
[image: screen after]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating displays programmatically in Windows XP? (C++/Qt and WindowsAPI)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625057/rotating-displays-programmatically-in-windows-xp-c-qt-and-windowsapi)

Comment: That question seems to be about rotating a single monitor so that it displays sideways, for instance. This question seems to be about arranging a multi-monitor setup arbitrarily (in this case, so that monitor 1 is above monitor 2, as in the screenshots).

Comment: I don't quite understand what ISN'T working... Are you showing what you WANT to have happen, or what actually happens? How is what actually happens different from what you desire?

Comment: Almost every "it doesn't work" question about [winapi] starts with a code that does not check for errors.  Do *not* ignore the return value of ChangeDisplaySettingsEx().

Comment: I can align monitor vertically from control panel but not from VC++.

Comment: Hans has a point - in particular, I expect that you can't set TWO monitors to "primary", perhaps?

Comment: @msl could you add error checks to your `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` call? and perhaps could you try what Mats Petersson is pointing out above (that you're trying to set both displays as primary)?

Comment: first of all thanks for reply @andlabs, and thanks hans-passant for pointing out unhanded return in ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(). I am now able to set vertical, extend, clone etc.. I will post it to github for anyone with similar query in future